# CPU usage limit to systemd-nspawn container is not working

Tags: systemd, cgroups, systemd-nspawn

I am using systemd-nspawn(systemd version 237) in Yocto's embedded Linux environment.

This is the content of `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn\@.service.d/override.conf` file

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-nspawn --quiet --boot --link-journal=try-guest --machine=%i -n --property=CPUQuota=10%
```

I am trying to load the CPU with "sha1sum /dev/zero &" or  "for i in 1 2 3 4; do while : ; do : ; done & done" inside the container but the top command on host shows that always they are at 50% CPU usage altogether(4 sh processes and one sha1sum process, if only sha1sum process is started, it alone uses 50% if not 10% each)

I am unable to understand if there is any other setting where this 50% limitation is coming from? And why CPU quota is not effective

Answer (score 0):

Since [cgroup v2](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/ControlGroupInterface/) is recommended now, I suggest to try the same command with cgroup v2. To do this, add [systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy) to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`, run `update-grub`, and reboot Linux. I hope cgroup v2 gives better CPU control to you.